# making array data able to be favorited and loaded in a table

Tags: iphone

hello i have an array that features data in an array of arrays.
its like the items in format root array 
rootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2",  nil];

i want to knw what action to give a uibutton in order to be able to change a boolean value to is_favorite for that cell and make it show in the favorite table.

so i want to have an `-(IBAction) makefavorite
//i have no idea how to implement this however to make the selected detailview controller and also its previus cell that was selected load in the favorites table.`

furthermore i heard of using the is_favorite boolean to make items appear in a favorite view however i heard that only applies to databases.

hope im more clear now

thanks

`translation attempt:`

> Hello, I have an array of data and I show the user some object out of that array in a "detailed view" so to speak.  Once the view shows some object in that array to the user, I want the user to have the option of saving that object to their "Favorites" by clicking a UIButton.  I would then like all of these "favorites" loaded into a UITableView with each item in the favorites array representing an individual table view cell.  So possibly I could store all of these "favorite" items into a set of NSUserDefaults each time a button is pressed?
>
> Could anyone elaborate more on how I could implement such a system?  I am very new to this and my English is not very good.  Thanks!

Comment: Dude, this question is completely incomprehensible. Please try to expand and/or clarify.

Comment: i fixed my descripton hopefully you can help me

Comment: I'm really sorry, but this question is unintelligible. Voting to close.

Comment: I haven't got a clue what you're asking here.  You need to clarify a lot more.

Comment: im asking how to make a favorites tab thats the big idea.
i want to be able to add items with a uibutton to the favorites...

Comment: Alex, I translated for you.  Keep in mind that not everyone knows your project or your wants as well as you do.  You have to explain things step by step and give clearer details of a) what you have already done; b) what you are trying to do; and c) what you really don't understand and need help with

Comment: thanks a lot, i looked everywhere but i havent found one tutorial on a favorites tab.

Comment: That may be because nobody else knows what a "favorites tab" is.  Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish from the user's perspective?

Comment: a tab that features items selected as favourites by the user...(using an uibutton)

Comment: He's talking about a tab bar controller and have a "Tab" being a new view (possibly a UITableView) with a set of favorites on it.

Comment: yes exactly that.... and i want to add an object to that 
"tab" using an uibutton...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on what I think you're saying, you're trying to add a button to mark some objects in an array as favorites?

You could create a model class that represents each object and give it a boolean property `favorite` or something, then simply do something like `([[rootArray objectAtIndex:someIndex] set] setFavorite:YES];` in your `makeFavorite` method. Alternatively, you could just use an `NSDictionary` with keys for the text and whether or not it's marked as favorite.

As for storing the favorites, `NSUserDefaults` is not appropriate for that. (`NSUserDefaults` should be used for anything related to user settings; basically, anything that you would expose in the Settings app). Instead, you would want to write your array to a file in one of the writeable folders when the application is suspended, and restore the array from the file when the application becomes active. (You could also use sqlite or some other form of storage if you wanted, but it sounds like you're storing relatively simple data so this isn't necessary).